# how to get column names from Hive table, if that column contains null values?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql

I tried with following queries, these queries giving only the count of null values, What i need was to do a null check and return the column name.

```
select count(*)-count(columnA), count(*)-count(columnB) from table;
select count(*) from table where columnA is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
SELECT 
  SUM(IF(columnA is NULL,1,0)) as canulls,
  SUM(IF(columnB is NULL,1,0)) as cbnulls 
FROM table;
```

This will also give you the number of null fields for each columns.